# Saving the in-order visit of a binary tree in an array

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, inorder

The question is the following:
is there an algorithm which, given an binary tree `T` and an array, allows to store in the array the result of the correspondent in-order visit of the tree?

Pseudo-code of a "normal" in-order visit:

```
inOrder(x){ // x is a node of a binary tree
   if(x != NIL){ // the node is not null
      inOrder(x.left)
      print(x.key)
      inOrder(x.right)
   }
}

// Function calling inOrder
printInOrder(T){ // T is a binary tree
   inOrder(T.root) // T.root is the root of the tree
}
```

Example:
Given the following tree

```
     5 
   /   \
  3     8
 / \   / 
2   7 1
```

the algorithm above should output `2 3 7 5 1 8`.

I'm sure this can be achieved and it shouldn't be too hard but I'm currently struggling for this problem.

Comment: Hint: keep track of the current index where the next element should be written in the array. If you have to do it without any mutable state other than the array, take that index as an argument and return what the new current index should be.

Comment: I already knew the first solution, although I feel like it can be improved (and i really really dislike it).
About the second one: how can I determine where the next element should be saved? In the example I have used an almost complete binary tree but the algorithm should be working for every tree.

Comment: Are there any limitations on passing variables (including the array to be populated with the output) to the `inOrder` function as parameters?

Comment: You just need to save the node in an array instead of "print(x.key)" statement. Take a global array "inorderNodes" and one global int variable say "idx" and set "idx=0" from the driver method, write "inorderNodes[idx] = x.key; idx++;" that's all.

Comment: There is no limitation on the inOrder parameters

Comment: Isn't there any other way? I'd need a solution that assumes no global state.

Comment: I don't understand the question. If you are worried about allocating memory dynamically, then as alternative you can do the tree traversal just to count the nodes, and then do the memory allocation, and then do the tree traversal to populate that array. Although you visit each node twice now, this does not impact the time complexity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing to an array (instead of printing) means you need to keep track of which index to write at in the array. If you need to do this without any mutable state other than the array itself, you need to pass the current index as an argument, and return the new current index.

The code below is written in [static single assignment form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_single_assignment_form) so even the local variables are not mutated. If that isn't required then the code can be simplified a bit. I'm assuming that the array length is known; if it needs to be computed, that is a separate problem.

```
inOrder(x, arr, i) {
    if(x == NIL) {
        return i
    } else {
        i2 = inOrder(x.left, arr, i)
        arr[i2] = x.key
        i3 = inOrder(x.right, arr, i2 + 1)
        return i3
    }
}

getArrayInOrder(T, n) {
    arr = new array of length n
    inOrder(T.root, arr, 0)
    return arr
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First about arrays : In order to populate an array you need to know the length of the array beforehand. If you don't need to specify the length for instantiating an array ( depending on the language that you use ) then that's not really an array. Its a dynamic data structure whose size is increased automatically by the language implementation.

Now I assume you don't know the size of the tree beforehand. If you do know the size, you can instantiate an array of specified size. Assuming you don't know the size of the array, you need to go with a dynamic data structure like `ArrayList` in Java.

So at each `print(x.key)` in your code, just append the `x.key` to the list ( like `list.add(x.key)` ). After the traversal is complete you may turn your `List` to `array`.

You could use [iterative](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/inorder-tree-traversal-without-recursion/) version of the traversal too.

One simple solution for recursive approach is to use a single element array to track the index like:

```
void inOrder(x, int[] idx, int[] arr):
    if x != NIL:
       inOrder(x.left, idx, arr)
       arr[idx[0]++] = x.key
       inOrder(x.right, idx, arr)
```

although I m sure there may be other ways that can become cumbersome (maybe). I prefer iterative version anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If your language / use-case allows putting ints into the array, you could store the index in the array. I'm going backwards because that's simpler then:

```
inOrder(x, arr){
   if(x != NIL){
      inOrder(x.right)
      arr[--arr[0]] = x.key
      inOrder(x.left)
   }
}

saveInOrder(T, n){
   arr = new int[n]
   arr[0] = n
   inOrder(T.root, arr)
   return arr
}
```